# Vue & Typescript: Image imports not found

Tags: typescript, vue.js

### Problem

I'm currently working on a Vue project using Typescript. Inside my assets folder I have some images I want to import with a separate Typescript file.

---

### Background

This project is bootstrapped by the vue-cli using Typescript, version `3.2.1`. What I have tried is directly importing into my file using require, which did not work. I then tried importing with `import` to no avail

---

### Code

This is what I've tried:

```
./src/myFile.ts
import Image from '@/assets/img/hello.png';
```

Does not work

```
./src/myFile.ts
import Image from '../assets/img/hello.png';
```

Does not work

```
./src/myFile.ts
const Image = require('../assets/img/hello.png');
```

Does not work

---

### Result

The bundler will throw an error along the lines of `Relative modules were not found` followed by the path of the file. I have made sure that the path is correct and I suspect this has to do with how TypeScript manages imports and how the Vue-cli is configured to bundle my files.

### Screenshot

Here is a screenshot of the actual project. The file path is `./src/views/World/Combat/Game.ts`:
[image: Project tree screenshot]

Comment: [The documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports) indicates that your last attempt (with `require`) should work

Comment: It's unclear what the correct path to your image should be. Can you please share a screenshot of your file hierarchy showing both `myFile.ts` and `hello.png`?

Comment: @Phil I have added a screenshot, thank you for pointing out

Answer (score 22):

Create a file named `shims-png.d.ts` in `/src/` with this content:

```
declare module "*.png" {
  const value: string;
  export default value;
}
```

Stop and run the app again.

Comment: Just to improve the above answer; you can create a file called "shims-png.d.ts" (whose content will be the answer code) and put it in the same dir as "main.ts"

Comment: I also had to restart `webpack-dev-server` in order to make it work. Not sure if that's the case of my config or dev server in general though, but keep that in mind.

Comment: In my case I had to restart VSCode before it stopped showing the error.

Comment: Instead of restarting VSCode, you can restart the language server. CTRL + SHIFT + P, then type "Vetur: Restart VLS (Vue Language Server)". At least if you're using the Vetur extension.

Comment: awesome, works in nuxt2

Comment: Worked for me only with `export = value`